# GraphQL - spread input args

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo

I'm trying to specify a GraphQL schema with a type that has various fields, and also allows you to tack on an `OR: [...]` recursively with the same arguments.  I've got it working like this

```
input BookFilters {
  _id: String
  title: String
  title_contains: String
  title_startsWith: String
  title_endsWith: String
  OR: [BookFilters]
}

type Query {
   allBooks(_id: String
     title: String
     title_contains: String
     title_startsWith: String
     title_endsWith: String
     OR: [BookFilters]
   ): [Book]
}
```

which works great, and this query

```
{
  allBooks(title_endsWith: "1", OR: [{ title: "2" }, {title:"3"}, {OR: [{title_contains: "Q"}, {OR:[{title:"Q"}]}]}]) {
    _id
    title
  }
}
```

goes through just fine.

My question is, is there some way to remove the duplication?  Ideally I'd love it if

```
type Query {
   allBooks(...BookFilters): [Book]
}
```

was valid, but it doesn't appear to be.

---

Edit - A comment brought up fragments.  They can only be declared *off of* a type, right?  So I'd still have a make a new type that lists all my query arguments, and then make a fragment off of it, re-listing all the fields?

Even if that's not so, GraphQL still doesn't seem to like spreading on input arguments.

```
fragment BookFiltersFragment on BookFilters {
    _id
}

type Query {
   allBooks(...BookFiltersFragment): [Book]
}
```

which errors out on the `...`

Comment: This reminds me of fragments. Check this out: http://dev.apollodata.com/react/fragments.html

Comment: Sorry thats Apollo, check the vanilla docs if you are using that.

Comment: Yeah - I saw fragments.  They're only declared on a Type though, right?  Regardless, it seems I still can't spread a fragment on query arguments

Comment: You've run the course of my aid; nice work tho, this is a fairly beast mode consideration you've uncovered.

Answer (score 1):

For the benefit of anyone winding up here, it looks like this is impossible, at least according to an Apollo dev.

https://twitter.com/stubailo/status/914997054098759680

https://twitter.com/stubailo/status/914997127356366848

Answer (score 0):

We build our schema from plain JS instead of the query language and are able to use the spread since our arguments are plain-old-javascript-objects.  I believe the "GraphQLInputType" is a fully-fledged instantiation that won't allow spreading easily.